# Given $e$ and $d$, find $\phi(n)$

Tags: rsa, public-key

Let's say we have just RSA public and private exponents $e$ and $d$ but not the corresponding modulus $n$. Is there a method to find $\phi(n)$?

This is for a CTF challenge. I am not concerned about retrieving $n$ at this stage.

My guess would be to start from $d = e^{-1} \mod \phi(n)$, which leads to $1 = e \times d \mod \phi(n)$.

Hence, $\phi(n)$ could be equal to $e \times d - 1$, but that could also not be the case, if $e \times d - 1$ is composite.

So is there a way to find the correct value for $\phi(n)$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, we have $1 = e \cdot d \bmod \lambda(n)$, where $\lambda(n) = \phi(n) / \gcd(p-1, q-1)$; that complicates things somewhat...

Comment: $1 = e \times d \mod \phi(n)$ is incorrect? Damn, if we have to know $\textrm{gcd}(p-1,q-1)$, then I really don't know how my problem could be solved. Obviously, we do not have access to $p$ or $q$.

Comment: The only reference I could find on this problem points to this paper https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/Papers/Mi76.pdf.

Comment: Is $e$ a Fermat prime like in most modern RSA implementations?

Comment: @forest Yes, it is 65537.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi Then if this is for a CTF, it's possible that the solution doesn't involve cryptanalysis. There might be some other resource on the system that gives you a hint as to the modulus, or $d$ might have been generated in such a way that it contains enough information to discover the modulus.

Comment: @forest The only things I have access to are 2 different ciphertexts `ct_a` and `ct_b` (the plaintexts are probably different as well), the two different private exponents `d_a` and `d_b`, and finally `e = 65537`. It must be noted that the two moduli `n_a` and `n_b` have a common factor, but I don't know how I could exploit this vulnerability without having access to `n_a`, `n_b`, `phi(n_a)` or `phi(n_b)`. Hence my question in this post.

Comment: $de-1$ is only a small factor away from $\phi(n)$, below $65537$. You can bruteforce it and proceed as if $(de-1)/f$, $f$ being your candidate, is the real $\phi(n)$.

Comment: In fact, in your situation, you probably don't need any of that; $\gcd(e \cdot d_a-1, e \cdot d_b-1)$ will give you the common factor (plus some easy to remove extraneous factors) between $n_a$ and $n_b$. It should be easy to go from there.

Comment: I believe it is common to have things hold mod $phi(n)$ even though RSA will work also with the more lenient requirements of $Lambda(n)$ for a CTF I would definitely try if the simple option works.

Comment: if we know d and e then we can guess the ${\phi(n)}$, since de-1= k${\phi(n)}$. for ex. if d=53 and e=17, ed-1=900, now finding factors of 900, i.e., ${\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 25, 30, 36, 45, 50, 60, 75, 90, 100, 150, 180, 225, 300, 450, 900}\}$
Now one can search p and q as ${\phi(n)=(p-1)\cdot(q-1)}$, for ex. 60=10x6, so p=11 and q=7 and then we can see if ${gcd(e,\phi(n))=1}$. Here we have to find the factor of a 900 only if adding one to it gives prime number. But finding factors of a large number we've to adapt different factorization method.